# Deleting objects in C++, and the new keyword

Tags: c++, memory, delete-operator

A few questions:

I was looking at the following code for a linked list on www.cprogramming.com:

```
struct node {
  int x;
  node *next;
};

int main()
{
  node *root;      // This will be the unchanging first node

  root = new node; // Now root points to a node struct
  root->next = 0;  // The node root points to has its next pointer
                   //  set equal to a null pointer
  root->x = 5;     // By using the -> operator, you can modify the node
                   //  a pointer (root in this case) points to.
}
```

1. Would this code cause a [small] memory leak because he never deletes root at the end?
2. Also, would this be any different if 'node' was a class instead of a struct?

Finally, for this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
A(){}
void sing()
{ cout << "TEST\n";}
};

int main()
{
A *a = new A();
a->sing();
return 0;
}
```

3. Would I have to delete A before exiting main?
4. In what instances would I use `A *a = new A()` versus using `A a = A()` ?

Comment: Classes and structs are nearly equivalent, and you should prefer `A a;`. If you need a pointer, use a smart pointer.

Comment: What does `A a = A();` achieve that `A a;` doesn't? Answer that and you'll answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

1.1 Yes, although on any modern operating system when the process ends all its memory is reclaimed by the operating system. Memory leaks are a big problem for long lived processes, where memory continues to be leaked and the process continues to ask for more memory for no apparent reason.

1.2 I suppose you meant a `class`, not an object (an object is an instantiation of a class or of a struct)... still, there would be no difference, `class` and `struct` differ only in their default access specifier (`public` for `struct`s, `private` for `class`es).

2.1 Yes (with the same caveat as in 1.1).

2.2 Usually when (a) `A` is too big to be placed on the stack, (b) when the object lifetime imposed by local variables (=automatic destruction at the end of the scope) is not appropriate, (c) when the number of objects to be create is not known at compile-time.

Examples:

a. `A` contains in its definition a really big matrix, that would take away a lot of stack space; or, `A` is not that big, but the current call is recursive, so putting it on the stack would be likely to lead to a stack overflow.

b. `A` is an object to be returned from this function (and a copy is not acceptable); or, `A` is to be created in this function and to be deleted in the future by some other function, but not at the end of the current scope.

c. `A` is a node of a linked list to be populated with data provided by the user; you create and append the nodes in a loop until the user provided data ends.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part:

1. It might be sloppy (and tools like Valgrind will warn about it), but all memory is freed by the OS when `main` returns. A memory leak is more of a concern if it persists as the program continues to run.
2. There is no distinction in C++ between "classes" and "structs". A `class` simply has its initial access modified as private rather than public.

And for the later part:

1. Same as 1.
2. This is a fairly complicated question. Broadly, you'll want to use heap memory allocation (which is what `new` does) in cases where the object needs to outlive the current scope (e.g. to be returned by the function in which it is constructed) or its size is determined dynamically or can be very large, among other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

> Would this code cause a [small] memory leak because he never deletes root at the end?

Yes, however the program is terminated and the memory should be reclaimed by the OS. So any memory leak checks would flag this.

> Also, would this be any different if 'node' was an object instead of a struct?

No. Structs and Classes are nearly identical, except that the default protection for a struct is `public`

> Would I have to delete A before exiting main?

Yes. To avoid a memory leak.

> In what instances would I use A *a = new A() versus using A a = A() ?

Using `operator new` will allocate the memory on the heap. It's preferred to allocated on the stack, unless you need your object to live past the life of the stack-frame, in which case you can either return by copy, or allocate it on the heap, where it will remain until it is deleted.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

#### First Part

1) Yes, there is a memory leak.

2) There is no functional difference between a class and a struct.

#### Second Part

1) Yes, you should delete any object that you allocate on the heap.

2) In any case where you can avoid pointers (and allocating heap memory, for that matter), you should. It takes less time and uses less resources to use the stack.
In this case the lifetime of the object is so short that it makes no sense to use the heap.